# can not load the css file

Tags: html, css

I know this is a very basic question but I cannot deal with it in this situation. I'm using Vertx. When I deploy my verticle which render **index.peb** file but cannot load the css files.

This is my folder :

[image: folder structure]

this is link to css file :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../statics/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

and the error :

> WARNING: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [Mon, 17 Feb 2020 03:19:48 GMT] "GET
>   /statics/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 53

Comment: thank @Smokey Dawson for editing my question

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is pretty simple, the href attribute in index.peb is referencing the wrong place for your css file.

The ".." means to go up one folder, so href = `../statics/css/bootstrap.min.css` never leaves the templates folder and attempts to reference a file at `templates/statics/css/bootstap.min.css`.

Fixing this is as simple as adding an extra `../` to the start:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../statics/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry everybody. I presented my question not clearly and I've not read vertx document completely. My CSS file can not be loaded because I don't set the web root folder in router.